# Configuring the Control Bar buttons on JWPlayer

Tags: jwplayer

I am trying to get rid of all the controls on my JWPlayer except play and progress bar.

I did this:-

```
jwplayer("myvideo").setup({
            autostart: true,

            controlBarMode:'floating',
            "controls": {
              "enableFullscreen": false,
              "enablePlay": false,
              "enablePause": false,
              "enableMute": true,
              "enableVolume": true
            },

            flashplayer: "scripts/vendor/jwplayer/player.swf",
            file: $scope.getCurrentSlide().video
        });
        if (!$scope.getCurrentSlide().video.length) {
            $(".video").hide(); 
        }
        else {
            $(".video").show(); 
        }
    });
```

But it just shows all of them.

Comment: In order to do this in JW6, you need to build a custom skin with only the controlbar present. We have a skin SDK available on our developer site here - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/

Comment: You can see my answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36430044/1386969 Dont forget to smile :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove certain buttons from controlbar you have to customize your own skin and remove them from skin xml file.